# IHTMLDocument2 e versões do Windows e IE

Tags: html, delphi

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de qual a incompatibilidade de algumas versões do *Windows* + *IE* com o uso de `IHTMLDocument2`?

### Exemplo:

```
IDoc := CreateComObject(Class_HTMLDOcument) as IHTMLDocument2;
v := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], VarVariant);
v[0] := xHtml;
IDoc .Write(PSafeArray(System.TVarData(v).VArray));
IDoc .designMode := 'off';

ovTable := (IDoc.all.tags('TABLE') as IHTMLElementCollection).item(1, 0);
ovTable.Rows.Item(I).Cells.Item(J).InnerText;
```

Na Maioria das versões do *windows*, *XP, 7-32x, 7-64x, 8-32x, 8-64x* isso funciona normalmente, consigo obter as tabelas e o conteúdo das células da maneira acima, isso com versões do IE, desde a 8 até a 11, mais em algumas instalações do *Windows*, isso simplesmente não funciona, não consegue obter a tabela e nem o conteúdo das células, como se não encontrasse no *html*

```
ovTable := (IDoc.all.tags('TABLE') as IHTMLElementCollection).item(1, 0);
ovTable.Rows.Item(I).Cells.Item(J).InnerText;
```

Alguém já teve o mesmo problema?

Sabe a causa/solução ou até mesmo alguma outra maneira de trabalhar o *html* (obtendo, tabelas, *forms*, células etc..) que não haja essa incompatibilidade com versões do *Windows+IE*?

Comment: Por favor especifique qual versão do Windows não funciona. Ou qual versão do IE não funciona para primeiramente reproduzirmos o problema. Em alguns casos, pessoas já passaram pelo problema então não seria necessário, outros casos, mesmo que não passaram pelo problema, entretanto, com o MVCE, conseguirão ajudá-lo mais facilmente